# Proving discontinuity - almost there again

Tags: real-analysis

This time the function is different (of course).

$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
$h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

and both are continuous.

I wish to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=h(x)$ if $x<c$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x\ge c$ is continuous if and only if $h(c)=g(c)$.

I have shown that $h(c)=g(c)\implies f(x)$ is continuous. I now want to go the other way, show it is discontinuous if $g(c)\ne h(c)$

I will have a $|f(x)-f(c)|$ in it and this is $=|f(x)-h(c)$| so I want to take $f(x)$ on the side $<c$ but really close to $c$ so $f(x)-h(c)$ becomes really close to $g(c)-h(c)$ which are different, thus I can find and epsilon.

From this I would pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}|g(c)-h(c)|$ because that is in between both and as they are not equal there is a point between them. This gives me a nice symmetry I may exploit (it's half way between either one)

I'm not sure how to complete this proof.

As before I sense I am close! Not quite there though.

**Addendum**

I might be able to use the "left side of c" (which there is because $\delta>0$) to get some $\epsilon_1$ (subscript because it may not be the same one) close to $g(c)$ I'll mess with this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to "flatten out" things: Assume $f$ continuous. As $g-h$ is continuous and is nonzero at $x=c$, it is nonzero in a neighbourhood of $c$. In this neighbourhood, $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)-h(x)}{g(x)-h(x)}$ is continuous. But this is $\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<c\\1&\text{if }x\ge c\end{cases}$ and should be well-known to be not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed very close. Choose $\epsilon= 1/2|g(c)-h(c)|$ as you wanted. Because $h$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $h(]c-\delta,c+\delta[)\subset ]h(c)-\epsilon,h(c)+\epsilon[$. Hence $f(]c-\delta,c[)=h(]c-\delta,c[)$ is at distance $\epsilon$ from $f(c)$. This shows that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: What does $]a,b[$ denote? $\mathbb{R}\backslash(a,b)$?

Comment: For me it is the open interval between $a$ and $b$. Maybe you write is $(a,b)$? I think this depends on countries, books, people...

Comment: That is a highly nonstandard notation. $(a,b)$ seems to be more universal both in mathematics and on this site.

Comment: Open interval, yes. I thought that's what it'd mean but the notation would make a lot of sense for what I said. Here $x\in(a,b)\iff a<x<b$ and $x\in[a,b)\iff a\le x<b$ (so $[a,b]$ is a closed interval). Then $]a,b[$ to mean the closed region that is not the open interval (a,b) makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Ok, I dont like $(a,b)$ because of the writing $f((a,b))$ but if you prefer, I can change it. According to Wikipedia, both are used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

Comment: It's okay I know what you mean (difficulty to read at a glance is good! It means I cannot copy, I must know!)

Comment: Nice way of thinking. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $\exists\epsilon$ such that $\forall\delta\exists x$ such that$ |x-c|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(c)|\geq\epsilon$.

Since $h$ is continuous, $\forall\epsilon_1>0\exists\delta_1$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1\Rightarrow |h(x)-h(c)|<\epsilon_1$.

Pick $\epsilon=\epsilon_1=\frac{|g(c)-h(c)|}{2}$. Let $\delta_1$ be the one that the definition of continuity of $h$ says exists. Then for every $x>c$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$, the definition of continuity of $h$ asserts that $|h(x)-h(c)|<\frac{|g(c)-h(c)|}{2}$. But then $$f(x)=h(x)>h(c)-\frac{|g(c)-h(c)|}{2}>g(c)+\frac{|g(c)-h(c)|}{2}$$, but the definition of continuity of $f$ tells us we need that inequality to go the other way.

Now we need to show that $\forall\delta$ some such $x$ exists, but the above is about $\forall x>c$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$, so $\forall \delta>0$ one can find such an x.

Comment: Small correction, $\ge\epsilon$ on the fist line, not $>$. Otherwise, lovely answer, I only ticked because I'm reading it now - after I solved the question. Thanks Stella.

Comment: Changing $\epsilon$ slightly turns a $>$ to a $\geq$, so it can be either way. The existence of once such $\epsilon$ guarantees that the other exists.

Comment: Certainly, I mean the definition of discontinuity (I try to be strict like this or write a note, that way I can see clearly why it isn't quite the definition)

Comment: Fair enough. Added

Answer (score 1):

Define $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ by $x_n:=c-\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n:=c+\frac{1}{n}$. Continuity of $g$ and $h$ gives us: $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}h(x_n)=h(c)\neq g(c)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}g(y_n)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f(y_n)$$

Therefore $\lim \limits_{x\to c}f(x)$ doesn't exist and $f$ is not continuous.